# Get row with maximum in one column

Tags: select

The task: What ingredients has the maximum amount of content in Pancake?

The tables:
Recipe (**Name**, group)
Ingredient (**Iname**, price)
Composition (**Name, Iname**, Amount)

I tried this query:

```
Select Iname, Amount
From Composition
Where Name='Pancake'
Ordered by Amount ASC
```

But it does not return the correct result. What's wrong with it?

Comment: It's `order by` not `ordered by`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)

Comment: Please edit your question to say what, specifically, is "got good" and how you would like it to improve.

Answer (score 2):

The typo in `ORDER BY` aside, you need *descending* sort order to get the ingredient with the maximum amount first.

```
SELECT Iname, Amount
FROM   Composition
WHERE  Name = 'Pancake'
ORDER  BY Amount DESC
FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Assuming `Amount` is defined `NOT NULL`.

`FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` is the syntax defined by the SQL standard and supported by several RDBMS, but not all. Depending on your undisclosed RDBMS you may need a different syntax variant. Here is a pretty complete list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#FETCH_FIRST_clause

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query, you need to join **Ingredient i** with **Composition c** `on i.iname=c.iname` with 2 condition `name='Pancake' and where amount >= select max(amount) from Composition where name='Pancake'`.

```
SELECT i.Iname, Amount 
FROM Ingredient i INNER JOIN Composition c ON i.iName=c.iName
WHERE Name='Pancake'
AND Amount >= (SELECT MAX(Amount) FROM Composition WHERE Name='Pancake');
```